# Jupyter Notebook Widgets: How to make "Filter As You Type" Textbox?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm trying to make a "filter as you type" textbox widget in my Jupyter Notebook in which if I write M it displays all players with "M"...if I type O after the M it displays players with "MO" in their name  (e.g. MOHAMED SALAH AND MO SALAH) and so on. The code below works quite well. The ONLY problem I'm having is that it keeps appending to the cell result...so if I write 3 letters it displays 3 tables. I want to clear the previous output so that I'd always have the latest result only. How can I do that?

```
import pandas as pd, IPython.display, ipywidgets as widgets 
out = widgets.Output()
display(out)

df = pd.DataFrame ({'PLAYER':['MOHAMED SALAH', 'MESSI', 'MO SALAH', 'RONALDO']})
display(df)

textbox = widgets.Text(value='', description='Player:')
display(textbox)

def display_result(value):
    value = str(value['new']).upper() 
    if "{" not in value: 
        print(value)
        result = df[(df['PLAYER'].str.contains(value))]  
        if result.shape[0]>0: display(result)


textbox.observe(display_result)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a call to `out.clear_output()` in your function!

```py
import pandas as pd, IPython.display, ipywidgets as widgets 
out = widgets.Output()
display(out)

df = pd.DataFrame ({'PLAYER':['MOHAMED SALAH', 'MESSI', 'MO SALAH', 'RONALDO']})

textbox = widgets.Text(value='', description='Player:')
display(textbox)

def display_result(value):
    value = str(value['new']).upper() 
    if "{" not in value:
        result = df[(df['PLAYER'].str.contains(value))]  
        out.clear_output()
        if result.shape[0]>0:
            with out:
                display(result)


textbox.observe(display_result)
```

Comment: Thanks...I copied your code and nothing is happening when I type in the textbox..can you kindly test from your side and let me know if it actually runs? I noticed it only works when taking out ```with out:``` but if I do that, the problem is still as it is (multiple tables). I suspect there's a bug with the ```out widget```?

Comment: Update: Your code works on Google Collab, but not on Jupyter Notebook..so there could be a bug with the widget...can you please test on your end on Jupyter and let me know if it works? Thanks

Comment: I wrote and tested this in jupyter notebook, with ipywidgets 7.4.2. What version of ipywidgets do you have?

Comment: Thanks for your help :-). I managed to resolve the issue. It was caused by nbextensions...the details could be found here for future reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236345/ipython-ipywidgets-bug-code-working-on-goolge-colab-but-not-on-jupyter-noteb)